# Stata how to export delimited files using 'file` in a loop

Tags: loops, stata

I'm importing dta files in a folder and exporting each to a csv file. I'm not sure why but the loop doesn't save the file. Here's the code:

```
global path "file path"
cd "${path}"

* Geocodes for edd
clear
local files: dir "${path}Data\MeasureData\" files "*_edd.dta"

*do loop to bridge file for EDD and 
foreach file in `files' {

    use "${path}Data/MeasureData/`file'", clear
    rename beafips edd_id
    merge m:1 edd_id using Data\TempData\bridge_edd.dta
    keep if _merge==3
    drop _merge
    export delimited "${path}Data\OutgoingData\`file'.csv", replace
    
}
```

I keep getting error like this:

file filepath\Data\OutgoingData.csv saved

I was expecting this to be saved as filepath\Data`file'.csv. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you can share a snippet of your data so we can reproduce your problem that'd greatly improve your chances of getting a helpful response (you can use dataex [ssc]) to do that. A few other thoughts (which I can't test without data) though: 1) you don't need to initialize the local on the line `foreach file in \`files'`. Try replacing that with `foreach file of local files`

Comment: 2) Based on the backslashes in your file path (i'm not convinced it's an error yet) it looks like you're using Windows; the combination of forward slash ``/`` and `\`` can cause issues on Windows machines so try changing the forward slashes in the line `use "${path}..."` to back slashes ``\`` and see if that helps. If neither of these things work, share some data

Comment: And 3) the reason why i'm not convinced it's an error is because Stata is telling you that it's saved a file somewhere. Perhaps you can find where by trying to locate the directory using `pwd` and looking in there to see what you have

Comment: @C.Robin Thank you for your comments. Yes you are correct, it was the backslash problem... So I should keep using / consistently ??

Comment: Give that a go. I actually got it the wrong way around (i'm a Mac user) and it's the combination of backslash ``\`` and `\`` that causes issues (not forward slashes). See here for a reference: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800310. If this helped solve your problem please do upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because Windows defaults to using backslashes in path directories, but in this context your computer is reading the backslash as an escape character and so isn't interpreting the ` as indicating the beginning of your local `files`.

This problem won't typically appear on a Mac/Linux machine as they default to using forward slashes in directory paths.

So the solution is to change all the `\`s to `/`s in your code. See here for a more detailed write-up of the problem: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800310